# Using POST via AJAX and PHP to send data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an object I am sending in an AJAX request:

```
 function send_value() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'get.php',
        data: {
            source1: "some text",
            source2: "some text 2",
            uniId: 3
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

I am trying to post them on click of a button

```
<head>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="get.php" method='post' name='sendform' onSubmit='send_value()'>
        <input type='submit' value='Test1'>
    </form>
</body>
```

Then I print the variables using PHP:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST["uniId"])) 
    {
        if ($_POST["uniId"] == 3) 
        {
            echo 'your logged in as '; 
            echo $_POST['uniId'];

            $src1 = $_POST['source1'];
            $src2 = $_POST['source2'];
            echo $src1;
            echo $src2;
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo 'sorry uniID is not correct';
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Im sorry the page was not able to load ";
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
```

Now the `uniID` is `3` so I hope to see:

```
your logged in as 3 some text some text2
```

But instead I get:

```
Im sorry the page was not able to load
C:\wamp64\www\mysite\get.php:20:
array (size=0)
empty
```

What is wrong in my code that the variables are not being posted and printing out in my PHP?

Thanks

Comment: remove `action="get.php"` from form and add return false in ajax request at end

Comment: Thanks,but have tried this and it dose not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the dataType

```
function send_value() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'get.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data:({"uniId":"test"}),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: and form like <form action="get.php" method="post" name="sendform" onsubmit="return send_value();">

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948002/submitting-form-via-jquery-ajax-post-request/39949050 you will find what you need

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're not preventing the standard form submission. Hence your `form` element is sent with no data as it contains no form control elements.

To fix this you can return the function output to the event handler:

```
<form action="get.php" method="post" name="sendform" onsubmit="return send_value()">
```

However and *much* better approach is to attach the `submit` event using unobtrusive JS and prevent the standard form submission. As you're using jQuery already, here's how you can do that:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'get.php',
            data: {
                source1: "some text",
                source2: "some text 2",
                uniId: 3
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<form action="get.php" method='post' name='sendform'>
    <input type='submit' value='Test1'>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rory, but dose not seem to fix the problem

Comment: Why's that? Any error messages? Which method have you attempted to use?

Comment: No its justprinting out the same as before and not getting the varibles

Comment: Have you checked the request in the console to ensure the data is being sent correctly?

Comment: when i use var dump it dose not see the variables, but ill try the console log

Comment: I do get a error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: ohhh, means jquery not included or older version @BenjaminOats

Comment: @devpro nice, ill add a new jquery CDN and try again with Rory's answer. thanks

Comment: Something must be wrong in another area of your code that you haven't mentioned here, as there's no reason this wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this form code

```
<head>

       <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="get.php" method="post" name="sendform" onsubmit="return send_value();">
        <input type='submit' value='Test1'>
    </form>
</body>
 <script>

 function send_value() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '2.php',
        data: {
            source1: "some text",
            source2: "some text 2",
            uniId: 3
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}

</script>
```

"get.php" FILE

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
    if (!empty($_POST["uniId"])) 
    {
        if ($_POST["uniId"] == 3) 
        {
            echo 'your logged in as '; 
            echo $_POST['uniId'];

            $src1 = $_POST['source1'];
            $src2 = $_POST['source2'];
            echo $src1;
            echo $src2;
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo 'sorry uniID is not correct';
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "Im sorry the page was not able to load ";
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
    ?>
```

This is the main thing:

```
<form action="2.php" method="post" name="sendform" onsubmit="return send_value();">
```

Comment: Would this work local like through wamp, as it just dose not work for me ?

Comment: I just get array (size=0)

Comment: I have also checked on wamp. Please make files name correct in form action attribute and in ajax url parameter.